# Insert trigger issue ,subquery returned more than 1 row

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

Trying to check if a vlaue entered in the inserted table column level_name matches with  the `Levels` table column level_name. My query returns an error `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` . Trying to write the code following Dan Guzman's one .

```
Declare @levelname nvarchar(MAX)= 
( 
 SELECT [LEVEL_NAME] + ' '
 FROM inserted 
 WHERE (select LEVEL_NAME from levels where level_name=(select level_name 
 from  inserted)) IS NULL 
 FOR XML PATH('') 
); 
if @levelname is not null 
BEGIN 
  RAISERROR(); 
END
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to use a trigger to enforce referential integrity? Not sure what table this trigger is intended for but this is either a foreign key or a unique constraint. Don't do this via code like this, it will cause you untold anguish in the long run.

Comment: I think it is because my requirement was to record the unmatched value in log

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use Top 1 In your query or use following format:

```
IF Exists(SELECT  [LEVEL_NAME]
          FROM inserted i
          INNER JOIN levels l ON l.Level_name = i.Level_name) Begin
  RAISERROR('Your error message',16,1); 
END
```

OR

```
IF (SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN levels l ON l.Level_name = i.Level_name)=0 Begin
  RAISERROR('Your error message',16,1); 
END
```

I suggest that use UNIQUE INDEX on level_name column. in order to restrict your user to insert duplication level_name value.

Comment: Thanks for the code but getting an error `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.`

Comment: have added `=0` in the where clause and getting the same error `more than 1 row` . updated code 
`IF Exists(SELECT  [GEOLEVEL_NAME]
          FROM inserted 
          WHERE (select GEOLEVEL_NAME 
                 from  RIF40_COVARIATES
                 where geolevel_name=(select geolevel_name 
                                   from inserted)) =0
 ) 
 Begin
  RAISERROR('geolevel name does not exit',16,1); 
END 
END`

Comment: you need to know that Inserted table have any rows or no. When you use Exists don't need to added `=0`.

Comment: I edit my question. if you want to use `=0`, must get count of rows from Inserted table.

Comment: still getting the error `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.` Here is the complete trigger code: `create  trigger tr_test
on [dbo].[test]
instead of insert, update
as
begin
 IF Exists(SELECT  [LEVEL_NAME]
          FROM inserted 
          WHERE (select LEVEL_NAME 
                 from [dbo].levels
                 where level_name=(select LEVEL_NAME 
                                   from inserted))
 ) Begin
  RAISERROR('Your error message',16,1); 
END
end`

Comment: I edit my post. you can use Inner join in order to get duplicate rows by name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @levelname NVARCHAR(MAX)= 
( 
 SELECT [LEVEL_NAME] + ' '
 FROM   inserted 
 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT LEVEL_NAME FROM levels
                    WHERE  level_name IN (SELECT level_name FROM inserted))
 FOR XML PATH('') 
); 
IF @levelname IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
  RAISERROR(); 
END
```

Comment: `insert into test(level_name) values('level_medium'),('level_high')` the code works if both levels are missing in the Levels table .if one missing and one exist the error is not being raised .

Comment: Now the code works if both are not missing but not if one missing and 1 exists .